# OS X brew installed hping but says command not found

Tags: macos, homebrew, apt-get

I've installed `hping` app via homebrew.

When I do brew list I get this response:

```
$ brew list

.... ... .... hping ... .... ...
```

however when I run my hping this happens.

```
$ hping
zsh: command not found: hping
```

and also this:

```
$ brew info hping                                                                                                                                                            
hping: stable 3.20051105
http://www.hping.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/hping/3.20051105 (9 files, 196K) *
  Built from source
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/hping.rb
```

I tried reinstalling it but it doesn't work. Very weird how this is possible. Couldn't find anything related to this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 17):

Add `/usr/local/sbin` to `$PATH`.
`hping` binaries are installed in `/usr/local/sbin`, not in `/usr/local/bin`.

EDIT: As @veslam says, you can add sbin by `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin`.

Comment: PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/sbin